# How can I start a process and give it a different name in Task Manager via a batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a batch file that looks like this:

```
cd C:\Some\Folder
wperl SomePerlScript.pl %*
exit 0
```

It's basically designed to work around the fact that perl.exe leaves an annoying command prompt window floating on my desktop; I want this script to run in the background without bothering me.

But when I do this, in Task Manager, I see "wperl.exe", instead of the name of the script. Is there any way to give the process a custom name, so I can remember what it is, and keep it from getting confused with any other wperl.exe processes I might start?

Comment: When you run a script with wperl, the process is wperl - wperl is executing the instructions in the script, the script is not its own process. If you want it to be its own process you will want to compile it- you can use something like this to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948405/how-to-compile-a-perl-script-pl-to-a-windows-executable-exe-with-strawberr (note that it doesn't technically compile, but it bundles the necessary routines in with the script so it is essentially self contained/separate process and runs on its own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wperl is the process executing the instructions contained in the script. While FreudianSlip's method will work (only because you change the name of the executable that is executing the instructions), it is a hacky way to handle it.

You're better off with [Perl2Exe](http://www.indigostar.com/perl2exe.php)

Write your script.
convert it with perl2exe:

```
perl2exe script.pl
```

You'll get an executable file called script.exe

run the executable and it will show up as script.exe in task manager.

To avoid the window that pops up, you can use [Quiet](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/quiet/) (note that the pro version of perl2exe will do this, but why pay the extra cost when Quiet is free?)

Your batch file would call your executable like so:

```
quiet script.exe
```

You now have a silent running version of your script that shows up in the task manager by name.

Answer (score 2):

We do this a little dirty ... we actually make a copy of the wperl.exe to something more obvious - i.e. someperlscript.exe.

```
cd C:\Some\Folder
copy c:\perl\bin\wperl.exe c:\perl\bin\someperlscript.exe
someperlscript.exe SomePerlScript.pl %*
del c:\perl\bin\someperlscript.exe
exit 0
```

Needs a little work for resilience etc, but you get the gist.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Start.exe` to specify window titles, and launch programs.  So maybe try something like:

```
cd C:\Some\Folder
start "My Window Title" /MIN /WAIT wperl SomePerlScript.pl %*
exit 0
```

That should start it minimized with your custom title.

Further to that, if you specify the script when you run the batch, you can use it's name as the title by passing an argument in.  Something like:

```
cd C:\Some\Folder
start %1 /MIN /WAIT wperl %1 %*
exit 0
```

Then run it with `myBatch.bat SomePerlScript.pl`.  It should then use whatever script name is provided as the title.

`Start.exe` has some other handy options you may like (/B to not create a window at all, ot /D to specify the path,e tc.).  Check out `Start /?` for more info.

---

As was pointed out by the OP in the comments, this doesn't affect the name in the Task Manager.

As FreudianSlip points out in his answer, renaming wperl.exe may be the only option.

Expanding on his idea, I'd suggest perhaps something like:

```
cd C:\Some\Folder
copy c:\perl\bin\wperl.exe c:\perl\bin\%1.exe
%1 %1.pl %*
del c:\perl\bin\%1.exe
exit 0
```

That way if you run `myBatch.bat SomePerlScript` it will rename the wperl.exe to match the name provided as the argument before running the `.pl` script with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really good explanation of how to use start.exe!

Comment: Hmm, didn't work. It still says "wperl.exe (32 bit)" in Task Manager.

Comment: Crappy. :(  I guess the Window Title doesn't affect what Task Manager lists the process name as (which I guess makes sense in the end).  I think you may be stuck (for lack of a better word) going the renaming route as FreudianSlip suggests in his answer.